# How to include Live Chat in more than one places on site.com page?

Tags: liveagent, site.com

I want to include Live Chat in more than one places on my site.com page, for example, header, footer, navigation, etc. But I found out that if we put the same code in more than one places on the same page, "Live Chat" link only shows up in one place. For example, if it shows up in header, it won't show up in footer or the navigation. Did it happen to anyone before? Is there a way to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the same element ID. We do this and I can confirm it is possible. Make sure the IDs used across the page are unique.